# Origin of the saying "ChatBot"?

Tags: etymology

I didn't found anything in Wikipedia or on the Web (Maybe I don't know how to search). Chat is speaking with someone. But what is bot? Is it came from robot? Where the word robot came from?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: If you know what *chat* is, but don't know what *bot* is, did you trying looking up *[bot](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bot)* in a dictionary?

Comment: It's not hard to find the definition of [robot](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/robot), either, and [its etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/robot) is interesting as well.

Comment: A good source of information for such answers is Webopedia (https://www.webopedia.com/), which defines "chatbot" and many other terms.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/new-words/chatbot/) the term was coined in the 90s by [Micheal Maudlin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Loren_Mauldin) from the terms *chatter* and *robot:*

> A chatbot is a a computer program that simulates interactive human conversation, usually over the internet. The use of chatbots has increased with the introduction of artificial intelligence precepts.
>
> Michael Maudlin invented the first chatbot program named Julia for Windows and the internet. ***Maudlin coined the term ChatterBot in the 1990s*** to describe these interactive conversation programs, *a combination of the words chatter which means informal, superficial talk and bot, an abbreviation for robot.*
>
> ***Within  a few years the term chatterbot was shortened to chatbot.*** Chatterbot and chatbot are portmanteaus, which are words that are formed by the melding of two unrelated words to create a new word. Synonyms for the terms chatbot and chatterbot are talkbot and Artificial Conversational Entity.
>
> Chatbots are used as online assistants, toys and on social media platforms such as Snapchat. Increasingly, chatbots are used in social media to influence public opinion.